# .bash_profile and $PATH // did I install it twice and are two lines (export... if... ) redundant?

Tags: bash, path

I just started learning programming and have a question regarding my
`.bash_profile` and my `$PATH`respectively.

My `.bash_profile`looks like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" 
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

and when I look up `$PATH` in the terminal, I get this:

```
-bash: /Users/Marc/.rbenv/shims:/Users/Marc/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin: No such file or directory
```

Shouldn't it just be one "export" and one "if" line in my `.bash_profile` - and can I just delete one line each in my `.bash_profile`?

My reasoning is that the second "export" and second "if" line is redundant since it does the same - or am I wrong?

Sorry, if the answer might be to obvious, since I am new and not really sure about it at all, I hope someone can help me.

Background info: I used Homebrew to install rbenv and ruby-build (installed Ruby, Bundler and RSpec)

Comment: Not only are they redundant, those two export statements result, because of the prepend operation, in a different final PATH than what a single one would've resulted in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that the duplicate lines are redundant. You should delete the duplicate lines and the next time you log on, you can check the contents of your PATH by running

```
echo $PATH
```

Duplicate lines are redundant (and possibly harmful) in every programming / scripting language that I've come across though there may be some esoteric language where this doesn't hold.

*On a related note:* since you're learning programming, you should try to follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If you ever find yourself repeating a piece of code, there's usually a better way of (re-)structuring your code.

Comment: @mkdirlab I wasn’t sure if your question was better suited for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/) but since there are already over 50,000 Bash related questions on Stack Overflow, I figured it was probably on-topic. If you considered the answer to be helpful, you should upvote it or accept it.  See [Upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-u) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And, oh yeah, welcome to the Stack Exchange network!